# How to calculate the area of each grid cell of a raster in Python?

Tags: python, raster, area, grids-graticules, cell-size

I have a square raster of size, let's say, 100x100 cells, with each cell being 200m X 200m. This raster is not in an equal-area projection, but is centered on the North Pole, meaning the actual area of each grid cell should change as you look further from the pole.

How do I calculate the area of each grid cell in Python? What I would like is to create an array which displays the area of each cell. Any ideas?

Comment: 1. Convert each cell into a polygon. 2. Reproject the polygon layer into an equal area projection. 3. Calculate the area in this projection.

Comment: What is the CRS of your raster?